# Calculating T(n) and BigO

Tags: python

I'm trying to find T(n) of this code:

```
def sequentialSearch(alist, item):
    pos = 0
    found = False
    while pos < len(alist) and not found:
        if alist[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos+1

    return found
```

I think that T(n) = (2+sigma(n)) and the BigO = n, but my question (well 2) is does that if statement add anything else besides just an n.  Also, does the variable being passed add anything in this case?  Am I thinking of this correctly?  Thank you!

Comment: Answer for random list `alist` is O(n). However for special formatted list answer may be between O(1) and O(n).

Comment: What is `T(n)`, and `sigma`? I assume it is related to complexity?